# Generate visual studio solution on mac with cmake

Tags: macos, visual-studio, cmake

Using the CMake GUI, for the same CMakeList, I am able to generate VS solution files on Windows and XCode solution files on Mac. However I am unable to generate VS solution on Mac, as I don't use any VS options under `Specify the generator for this project`.

I have VS 2017 Community for Mac installed on the Macbook. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Visual Studio for Mac is very different from Visual Studio.

The former is based on [Xamarin Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin#Xamarin_Studio), a product of Xamarin Inc., which was acquired by Microsoft in early 2016. Microsoft then basically rebranded Xamarin Studio as Visual Studio for Mac. Note that Xamarin Studio was mainly an IDE for developing mobile apps. Visual Studio for Mac [currently has no support for C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/?view=vsmac-2022#languages).

Because of this, CMake currently does not support Visual Studio for Mac. The Visual Studio generators that ship with CMake only work with the Windows versions of Visual Studio.

And before someone asks: They also don't work with Visual Studio Code, which is yet another product that has little in common with Visual Studio except the name. Unlike Visual Studio for Mac however, Visual Studio Code has extensive support for C++ development with CMake through plugins and might be a viable alternative if you're looking for a Visual Studio-like development experience for C++ on Mac.

In that case, you open the workspace *directly* with VS Code and let its CMake plugins handle the configuration of CMake. You will *not* use the Visual Studio generators of CMake for VS Code, as VS Code is unable to work with the generated solution files.

Comment: Is this still the case today? I have the same problem as the OP

Comment: @koegl Still [true today](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/?view=vsmac-2022#languages). Although the C++ support in Visualt Studio Code has improved significantly since the original answer and would now be my recommended IDE for doing C++ on Mac OS.